# Google Docs amalgamated history diff: Is it really once only?

Tags: google-docs

If several edits have been made since the last time I viewed a document, Google Docs gives a link at the top of the document that takes you to a special view showing ALL of these changes.

However, if you back out of that view, or are forced to re-login, etc., it seems like that option is gone forever: Only the normal ability to view one set of changes at a time remains.

Is that true or is there some trick to get the special multi-change "everything since last time" view back after the first time it's offered?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to get the button your're asking about back at this time.